# How to display dates between to given values along with another column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table (A) and I would like the end result to look like (B). Does anyone know how I can accomplish this task?? I'm guessing a loop/stored procedure, but I'm not sure and I'm fairly new to loops and stored procedures.

```
(A)
Name    str_date        end_date
Lorenzo 2010-10-09  2010-10-11
Karen   2010-09-10  2010-09-10
Mike    2010-06-01  2010-06-03

(B)
Name     Date
Lorenzo  2010-10-09
Lorenzo  2010-10-10
Lorenzo  2010-10-11
Karen    2010-09-10
Mike     2010-06-01
Mike     2010-06-02
Mike     2010-06-03
```

Comment: "I'm fairly new to loops and stored procedures" --- so? We all are new in something. Have you tried anything to solve *your* task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont even try to do this in mysql, use your server side programming language to format data.

and if you really, really, really want to: 
 create a table with all dates needed (i.e. since 1970-01-01 to 2030-01-01) and do something like (untested):

```
 -- ddl 
 CREATE TABLE all_dates ( date DATE, PRIMARY KEY (date) );

 -- query
 SELECT ad.date, A.Name
 FROM all_dates ad
 JOIN A ON A.str_date <= ad.date AND A.end_date >= ad.date
```

but still its server side task, not db.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP isn't trying to format his data - `*ISO` is probably how it appears normally - he's trying to pivot it.  Which he should create a Calendar file for (which are _immensely_ useful for all businesses).  There _are_ ways to generate them with recursive CTEs; unfortunately they won't work in MySQL, so it'll end up being a server-side generation program, or a script.

Comment: Thanks folks, your responses really helped me resolve my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
/* create view that will help us to to create calendar table */
create or replace view n as select 0 as n union all select 1 union 
    select 2 union select 3 union 
    select 4 union select 5;
drop temporary table if exists cal;
/* create calendar table */
create temporary table cal (d datetime primary key);
set @i = 0;
/* select min date value */
select @d := min(str_date) from tab;
/* create table with dates based on min date*/
insert into cal
select date_add(@d, interval @i := @i + 1 day) from n a, n b, n c, n d, n e;

/* join date to calendar table */
select Name, c.d as Date
from tab t
join cal c on t.str_date <= c.d and t.end_date >= c.d
order by c.d desc;
```

Don't forget to clean up:

```
drop view if exists n;
drop table if exists cal;
```

Result:

```
Name        Date
Lorenzo     2010-10-11 00:00:00
Lorenzo     2010-10-10 00:00:00
Lorenzo     2010-10-09 00:00:00
Karen       2010-09-10 00:00:00
Mike        2010-06-03 00:00:00
Mike        2010-06-02 00:00:00
```

**Added** simpler version:

```
/* create view that allows generate integers */
create or replace view n as select 0 as n union all select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9;

/* use generated integers to generate dates and join them */
select Name, c.d as Date
from tab t
join (
    select date_add(t.d, interval i day) as d
    from (select min(str_date) as d from tab) t
    join (select a.n + b.n * 10 + c.n * 100 + d.n * 1000 as i from n a, n b, n c, n d) n
) c on t.str_date <= c.d and t.end_date >= c.d
order by c.d desc;
```